# Capture UIImage frame of AVPlayer streaming .m3u8 for given time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, calayer, avplayer

So I have an AVPlayer that playing a live stream of an .m3u8 video and from what I've found searching it looks like you can't use AVAssetImageGenerator to make a screen shot but instead should use AVPlayerItemVideoOutput and

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)copyPixelBufferForItemTime:(CMTime)itemTime itemTimeForDisplay:(CMTime *)outItemTimeForDisplay
```

but when I try and get the outputs from my AVPlayer.

```
NSArray *outputs = self.mainPlayer.currentItem.outputs;
```

I get an empty array.

The video plays just fine.  Ultimatly what I want is a method like this.

```
-(UIImage *)frameFor:(CMTime)time;
```

At some point the CALayer on the view needs to be getting this image data so their has to be a way to grab that at some point.  I tried just capturing the CALayer my AVPLayerLayer is attached to but I don't get anything more than the blank view color (bright pink just to make sure its return something).  Their has to be some way of grabbing this data.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an empty array when you do

```
NSArray *outputs = self.mainPlayer.currentItem.outputs;
```

because the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` object needs to be added first

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]};
self.videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:settings];
[playerItem addOutput:self.videoOutput];
```

and then when the `AVPlayerItem` status is `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` you can capture the current frame using `copyPixelBufferForItemTime:itemTimeForDisplay`. For that, you need to create your `AVPlayer` object and add an observer to the `AVPlayerItem` status property

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[self.player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:NULL];
```

and then in your callback function

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (self.player.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)
    {
        CMTime currentTime = self.player.currentItem.currentTime;
        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self.videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];

        CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:buffer];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage];

        // use `image`
    }
}
```

If you only need to capture a thumbnail and you don't have to play the video first, you can use a simple utility that I've created that follows this logic.
(https://github.com/acotilla91/ACThumbnailGenerator)

How to use:

```
double bitRate = 1000000; // force video bit rate (can be use to cap video quality and improve performance). Pass 0 to use default bit rate.
self.thumbnailGenerator = [[ACThumbnailGenerator alloc] initWithPreferredBitRate:bitRate];

NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"];
int position = 10; // video position (in seconds) from where thumbnail should be extracted. Always pass 0 for live streams.

[self.thumbnailGenerator loadImageFrom:videoURL position:position withCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *image) {

    // use `image`            

}];
```

Hope it helps.

**Swift version:**
[ACThumbnailGenerator-Swift](https://github.com/acotilla91/ACThumbnailGenerator-Swift)

Usage:

```
var generator: ACThumbnailGenerator!

func captureSomeImage() {
    let streamUrl = URL(string: "https://p-events-delivery.akamaized.net/18oijbasfvuhbfsdvoijhbsdfvljkb6/m3u8/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8")!
    generator = ACThumbnailGenerator(streamUrl: streamUrl)
    generator.delegate = self
    generator.captureImage(at: 300)
}

func generator(_ generator: ACThumbnailGenerator, didCapture image: UIImage, at position: Double) {
    // Use `image`
}
```